# how to calculate zero values in array between two valid numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers with some 0 values. I want to fill 0 with the linear difference between two valid values.

let arr = [10,0,0,16,17,0,23]
I am using the below code to calculate the linear difference between the two data points if they have zero between them like 10 and 16 have two indexes with 0, if need any further info regarding this data feel free to comment below
any answers are accepted that can help.

```
let arr = [10,0,0,16,17,0,23]
//required result [10,12,14,16,17,20,23]
// here is my code

const getValueIf = (item, index, array) => {
  const lastindex = array.length - 1;
  const zeroWithFirst = index !== 0 && item === 0;
  const zeroWithLast = index !== lastindex && item === 0;
  const firstZero = index === 0 && item === 0;
  if (firstZero) {
    return array[index] = ifZeroToNumber(array, index) ;
  }
  if (zeroWithFirst || zeroWithLast) {
    if (zeroWithFirst && !zeroWithLast) {
      return array[index - 1];
    }
    if (!zeroWithFirst && zeroWithLast) {
      return array[index + 1] === 0 ? array[index + 2] : array[index + 1];
    }
    array[index] =
      (ifZeroToNumber(array, index) - array[index - 1]) / 2 +
      array[index - 1];
    return (
      (ifZeroToNumber(array, index) - array[index - 1]) / 2 + array[index - 1]
    );
  } else {
    return item;
  }
};

const ifZeroToNumber = (array, index) => {
  let num = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
    if (num === 0 && array[index + i]) {
      num = array[index + i];
    }
  }
  if (!num) {
    num = array[index - 1];
  }
  return num;
};
let removeZero = arr.map((value, index) =>
    getValueIf(value, index, arr)
  );
console.log(removeZero)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's loop through the array, once we find a zero, if it is the first one, remember the position, if it is the last, compute the step and fill:

```js
function fill(a) {

    let start = -1
    let zero = false

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === 0) {
            zero = true
            continue
        }

        if (zero && start >= 0) {
            let step = (a[i] - a[start]) / (i - start)
            for (let j = start + 1; j < i; j++)
                a[j] = a[j - 1] + step
        }

        zero = false
        start = i
    }

    return a
}

console.log(...fill([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 8, 9, 0, 11, 0, 0]))
console.log(...fill([12, 23, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 10]))
console.log(...fill([10, 0, 0, 16, 17, 0, 23]))
```

Comment: The code before editing was working and was consistent but now it is not consistent if you test it with the following array [12,23,0,0,0,25,0,0,15]
here are the result for the above array

Comment: Here are the result for the above array
[12, 23, 21.857142857142858, 20.714285714285715, 19.571428571428573, 18.42857142857143, 17.28571428571429, 16.142857142857146, 15]
it simply ignores the "25" value between 23 and 15

Comment: The only issue with the previous code I found was it gives NAN when the first item is zero and that can be fixed if we add a condition that if the step is true only and only then the next for loop should be executed
like
 let step = (a[end] - a[start]) / (end - start)
            if(step){
                for (let j = start + 1; j < end; j++) {
                    a[j] = a[start] + step * (j - start)
                }
            }

Comment: @AliNawaz: bugs fixed!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const removeZeroes = (arr) => {
    let a = [...arr]
    let start = -1
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] !== 0)
            continue;
            
        if (a[i - 1] !== 0) 
            start = i - 1
            
        if (a[i + 1] !== 0) {
            let end = i + 1
            let step = (a[end] - a[start]) / (end - start)
            if(step){
                for (let j = start + 1; j < end; j++) {
                    a[j] = a[start] + step * (j - start)
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return a
  }
  const arr = [0.0,0.0,0,200,0,100,0,0,15]
  console.log(removeZeroes(arr))
```